# Spring Caching's AbstractCacheInvoker doPut() method calls RedisCache put() method by mistake

Tags: java, caching, redis

I have a web application written in spring boot, that uses springframework.cache, and everything worked fine until I started using spring-data-redis.

As soon as I add spring-data-redis in the pom.xml, my spring cache starts using the RedisCache implementation. I want to use redis for the redis streams part on a different thing, and somehow ignore the redis cache implementation for the caching part of the app

Excpetion classpath:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: ...DomainData
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:96)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementWriter.write(DefaultRedisElementWriter.java:43)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.write(RedisSerializationContext.java:287)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.serializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:244)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:150)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:837)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:430)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:346)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
assessment-service_1  |         at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to explicitly set the property `spring.cache.type`, if Spring Data Redis is detected it is configured automatically to use Redis. You can pick values from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheType.html or completely disable using 'none'. You might need to add `spring-boot-starter-cache` to your POM to get the basic cache implementations.

Comment: Yes, thank you for answering. That is exactly what I did. I specified it to use the SIMPLE (Simple in-memory cache), and it worked.